# While trying to install scipy using python3.5 -m pip install -r requirements.txt I get the following error

Tags: python, macos, scipy

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.5/bin/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/tmpkrxa23jc
cwd: /private/var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/pip-install-diqfewju/scipy
Complete output (106 lines):
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
NOT AVAILABLE

```
openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

system_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.5/3.5.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

setup.py:420: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-osg1yar_'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])))
Running from scipy source directory.
/private/var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-kks_w38u/overlay/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
/private/var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-kks_w38u/overlay/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
/private/var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-kks_w38u/overlay/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
  File "/private/var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-kks_w38u/overlay/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 161, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    self.run_setup()
  File "/private/var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-kks_w38u/overlay/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 254, in run_setup
    self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
  File "/private/var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-kks_w38u/overlay/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
    exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
  File "setup.py", line 540, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 536, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/private/var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-kks_w38u/overlay/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 435, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError(msg)
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.5/bin/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/y9/qznk7l1s0r9_dljvgc9ls_pr0000gn/T/tmpkrxa23jc Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: try installing it with `pip install scipy`

Comment: I have already tried it.

Comment: What error did that produce? Also, what're you trying to do with the -m flag. -m flag is used to run module as a script

Comment: It's the same error. I also tried `brew install lapack` and `brew install openblas`. and then ran `pip install scipy` Still gives the same error